# CSS transition fade in-out is linear at start

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a form that changes border color(red-green) if the inputted values are correct or not - I also change between two small icons (glyphicon-ok and glyphicon-remove) at the end of each field.
I wanted to add a transition effect on the border color and icons(ease-in-out).

On the border color works perfectly but I noticed on the icons even though I set 'ease-in-out' the very first transition it's still 'linear' - the icons come in from the bottom like something pushes them up - I want them just to simply appear with a 0.2s transition.

Here is my css for the icons:

```
.start-label .glyphicon-ok  {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 19px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #ACCB71;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.start-label .glyphicon-remove  {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 19px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #CC3E44;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I have only these transitions in my entire css code with the border ones.
The transition for the border is the following:

```
transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or this is how it supposed to work?

Comment: you have to specify that the transition is on the color

Comment: The solution was so easy! Thank you!

Comment: no problem at all, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dorvalla's help I resolved it by specifying the transition on the color.

From:

```
transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

To:

```
transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
```